# Saving to table works first time but not second time results in error: NOT NULL constraint failed in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I get the error `(sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: quiz1.user_id` when I try saving to my table a second time. The tables are defined in my models.py file as:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    quiz = db.relationship('Quiz1', backref='author', uselist=False)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

class Quiz1(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    q1ans = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    q2ans = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    q3ans = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    q4ans = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

In my routes.py file I have

```
@posts.route("/quiz", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def taste_quiz():
    form = QuizForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        quiz = Quiz1(q1ans=form.q1ans.data, q2ans=form.q2ans.data, q3ans=form.q3ans.data, q4ans=form.q4ans.data,
                     author=current_user)
        db.session.add(quiz)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your responses have been saved', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
    return render_template('taste_quiz.html', form=form)
```

When I click submit on the quiz form for the first time, the code executes as expected. When I try to submit it again it gives me the NOT NULL constraint failed error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: quiz1.user_id
[SQL: INSERT INTO quiz1 (q1ans, q2ans, q3ans, q4ans, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('3', '4', '5', '6', None)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)
```

If I delete the record manually from the database and then submit the quiz form again, it works as expected but then trying it another time causes it to fail again.

If there is more code that you need to see, please let me know and I will update the question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you confuse `author` with `user_id` when creating the `Quiz1`?

Comment: I think it should be like that in your user model. 
```quiz = db.relationship('Quiz1', backref=db.backref('author', uselist=False))```

Comment: @KlausD. I don't think so? I just updated the question to include my post table and it is set up the same way and it works fine.

Comment: @Detlef that worked!! thanks so much. If you want to answer the question, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Detlef I'd also love it if you could explain why yours works and mine doesn't. I was getting my syntax from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JI76IvF9Lwg where it says to write it the way I had it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like that in your user model.

```
quiz = db.relationship('Quiz1', backref=db.backref('author', uselist=False))
```

You have implemented a [one-to-many](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) relationship and used [uselist](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.uselist).
You have several Quiz1 records for one user.
But only one user record for a Quiz1 record.
Thus the variable "quiz" is a list and its counterpart "author" is not.

Which relationship you define depends on the table in which the ForeignKey is created. This defines the reference to which table is referred.
If the key is saved in the "quiz1" table and references a certain "user" entry, then a quiz object can only have one user as the author. But several quiz objects can have the same user id stored in the foreignkey column.